# DialogFlow Android SDK needs grpc-okhttp, but adding it resulting to crashing of Socket IO CLient

Tags: android, kotlin, socket.io, dialogflow-es, grpc

Environment details

Issue with DialogFlow Android SDK v2.1.0

Steps to reproduce

1. I have implemented Chat Bot in my Android app using DialogFlow. I imported DialogFlow sdk using gradle implementation.
2. I got a crash saying that java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field IS_RESTRICTED_APPENGINE of type Z in class Lio/grpc/internal/GrpcUtil
3. Based on search results i got in Google Search to solve this issue, I had to add io.grpc:grpc-okhttp sdk. So, I added it and this issue has been solved but got one more issue.
4. My Android app project also have Socket IO Client. When I initialise the socket client, I'm getting a crash saying No virtual method callEngineGetConnection(Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Call;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Connection; in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/Internal;
5. If i remove grpc-okhttp then Socket is working fine.

Code example

If you want to test it out, this code can reproduce the issue

Socket Initialisation

```
val socket = IO.socket("URL_HERE")
socket.connect()
```

DialogFlow initialisation

```
val stream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.credentials)
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream)
val projectId = (credentials as ServiceAccountCredentials).projectId

val settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder()
val sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build()
val sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings) //This line causes the crash
val session = SessionName.of(projectId, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
```

This is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.identiygroup.career"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField("String", "googleApiKey", googleApiKey)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.3'

    //Crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'

    //CarouselView
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'

    //exo-player
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.1'

    //PDF
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation files('../libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //Navigation drawer
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:7.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bassaer:chatmessageview:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation ('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0')

    //Dagger
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01'

    //Retrofit
    implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.7.2'

    //RecyclerView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'

    // DialogFlow
    implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-dialogflow:2.1.0') {
        exclude group: "com.google.code.findbugs"
        exclude group: "javax.annotation"
    }
    implementation ('io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.29.0')
}

configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'protolite-well-known-types')
configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.protobuf',module: 'protobuf-javalite')
configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.protobuf',module: 'protobuf-lite')
configurations.implementation.exclude(group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'annotations')
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Stack trace

When grpc added

```
2020-07-01 22:59:15.216 6416-6668/com.identiygroup.career E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.identiygroup.career, PID: 6416
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method callEngineGetConnection(Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Call;)Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Connection; in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/Internal; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Internal' appears in /data/app/com.identiygroup.career-A85sKgM7VblLOhTeCZWZzQ==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.createWebSocket(WebSocketCall.java:154)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall.access$000(WebSocketCall.java:42)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.ws.WebSocketCall$1.onResponse(WebSocketCall.java:102)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:177)
        at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

When grpc not added

```
2020-07-01 23:03:03.749 7633-7633/com.identiygroup.career E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.identiygroup.career, PID: 7633
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field IS_RESTRICTED_APPENGINE of type Z in class Lio/grpc/internal/GrpcUtil; or its superclasses (declaration of 'io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil' appears in /data/app/com.identiygroup.career-iEEqTKViLiYphc8hCE-Q8w==/base.apk!classes5.dex)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.createSslSocketFactory(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:451)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:418)
        at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:513)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:314)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1600(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:71)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:210)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:217)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:200)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:156)
        at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.stub.GrpcSessionsStub.create(GrpcSessionsStub.java:78)
        at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.stub.SessionsStubSettings.createStub(SessionsStubSettings.java:108)
        at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.<init>(SessionsClient.java:132)
        at com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.SessionsClient.create(SessionsClient.java:114)
        at com.identiygroup.career.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.kt:141)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7826)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7815)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1318)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3355)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3519)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2126)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7709)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Any additional information below

In simple words, if grpc not added, Dialog flow crashing. If grpc added Socket is crashing.

Comment: Getting same issue @Syed Zeeshan have you resolve it? then please update the answer

Comment: Hey @Shweta Nandha, I have updated answer check it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62708293/9618090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Firestore and grpc okhttp overriding the com.squareup.okhttp. so we need to exclude square up okhttp from grpc and firestore so that these both don't override squareup okhttp

```
implementation ('io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.30.1') {
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp"
}

implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3') {
    exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest SocketIO client. It'll use the okhttp3 APIs which don't conflict with gRPC. Also consider upgrading your dependencies whenever you run into problems like this.

Comment: However, I figured out what's the issue. Dialogflow flow needs grpc okhttp. But implementing grpc leading to override of com.squareup.okhttp. so, I excluded squareup ok http like implementation (grpc-okhttp) { exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp" } then the issue is solved. Later I had to include firestore also. After adding firestore, the crash happened again. I suspected that firestore also using some kind of okhttp. I did the same with Firestore too. implementation (firestore) { exclude group: "com.squareup.okhttp" } Now All ok.